# Using osquery wildcards for multi-level patterns

Tags: inotify, osquery

I am using osquery v4.1.1 to monitor file events on a ubuntu box.

```
$ osqueryi --line "SELECT version, build, platform FROM os_version;"
version = 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
build =
platform = ubuntu
```

```
$ osqueryi --line "SELECT version from osquery_info;"
version = 4.1.1
```

I am trying to watch all the files within the `/etc/` directory, recursively, which has the extension `.conf` using the following wildcard: `/etc/%%/%.conf`. But, it also reports any files under `/etc/`. If I create a file `/etc/foo`, it created a file event for the `CREATED` event and others with it.

Minimal config to re-produce:

```
{
  "schedule": {
    "file_events": {
      "query": "SELECT * FROM file_events",
      "interval": "5",
      "removed": "false"
    }
  },
  "file_paths": {
    "sys": ["/etc/%%/%.conf"]
  }
}
```

These are the file events that I get when I do `touch /etc/foo`.

```
{"name":"file_events","hostIdentifier":"<hostname>","calendarTime":"Mon Dec 30 13:56:03 2019 UTC","unixTime":1577714163,"epoch":0,"counter":0,"numerics":false,"columns":{"action":"CREATED","atime":"1577714161","category":"sys","ctime":"1577714161","gid":"0","inode":"389945","mode":"0644","mtime":"1577714161","size":"0","target_path":"/etc/foo","time":"1577714161","uid":"0"},"action":"added"}
{"name":"file_events","hostIdentifier":"<hostname>","calendarTime":"Mon Dec 30 13:56:03 2019 UTC","unixTime":1577714163,"epoch":0,"counter":0,"numerics":false,"columns":{"action":"ATTRIBUTES_MODIFIED","atime":"1577714161","category":"sys","ctime":"1577714161","gid":"0","inode":"389945","mode":"0644","mtime":"1577714161","size":"0","target_path":"/etc/foo","time":"1577714161","uid":"0"},"action":"added"}
{"name":"file_events","hostIdentifier":"<hostname>","calendarTime":"Mon Dec 30 13:56:03 2019 UTC","unixTime":1577714163,"epoch":0,"counter":0,"numerics":false,"columns":{"action":"UPDATED","atime":"1577714161","category":"sys","ctime":"1577714161","gid":"0","inode":"389945","mode":"0644","mtime":"1577714161","size":"0","target_path":"/etc/foo","time":"1577714161","uid":"0"},"action":"added"}
```

#### Questions :

- Is `/etc/%%/%.conf` even a valid and usable wildcard ?
- If not, is there a way to achieve the required watch ?
- If yes, why is it not filtering the events based on the glob ?

I could find the following function: [filesystem.cpp#replaceGlobWildcards()](https://github.com/osquery/osquery/blob/master/osquery/filesystem/filesystem.cpp#L353) but could not understand what exactly it's trying to do apart from trying to extract the base path with no wildcards.

Also, I know that it uses [fnmatch](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch) but how does it convert the SQL like pattern to fnmatch compatible expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIM section of the configuration is a fairly broad set of rules about how to setup the inotify watches. You cannot infix a recursive expansion, this is called out in the [documentation](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment/file-integrity-monitoring/)

You could use something like `/etc/%/%.conf`, but that would only get you a single level of search.

I think you have 2 mechanisms to get the result you like.

You could setup FIM to watch all of `/etc/%%` and then have your query include an appropriate WHERE clause. Perhaps `SELECT * FROM file_events WHERE target_path like "%.conf"`

Or you could look at the `file_paths_query` options, and use a sql query to expand the search list. This is also in the [documentation](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment/file-integrity-monitoring/)

Comment: I had totally missed that example of `/Users/%%/Configuration.conf` not being a valid expression. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No problem!  I hope osquery is useful

Comment: I tried using `file_paths_query` with the following query and it works as expected. `sSELECT path FROM file WHERE (directory LIKE '/etc/%%' OR directory LIKE '/etc/') AND filename LIKE '%.conf';`